# Facet pages bring site down because of bots

Tags: 7, search

We have a search page that uses facets and recently our website has been going up and down.  When looking at the logs I noticed that bots (Bing, Ahrefs, etc..) are hitting these facetted pages a lot.  Since the facetted pages are not cached I think it is causing this issue.

I did add Search-specific caching but that did not help.

I have seen these related issues with caching and facets:

- [facets will disappear, when you enable caching for a views page](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/1438856)
- [Facet blocks not displayed with cached Search API View](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi/issues/2016839)
- [Facet blocks disappear when Views caching is enabled](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/1612708)

Has anyone else ran into an issue like this?  For now I blocked all bots from accessing the facetted urls (so they will still be able to see the main search page).

Answer (score 0):

For example, my facet page path starts with `/library`.  I created a Firewall rule in Cloudflare to block anyone visiting a page that contains `/library/` so a facet result page like `/library/xxx/bbb/ccc` and is a known bot will be blocked.

[image]